# str.replace selected columns instead

Tags: python, pandas

quite sure there is a simple fix for this, but I've not been able to figure this out and the documentation has offered me no solution thus far.

please see a sample of my original data below:

```
Access Point : Main Site, Blog, Twitter, Facebook.
User 1:        Yes        No    Yes      no
User 2:        No         Yes   No       Yes
Did this: used search, used blog, used email service.
user 1:        Yes     Yes        No
user 2:        No      Yes        Yes
```

with the help of the SO community, I've put together a nice workable script to

change the Yes's into column names whilst stripping useless content (in a reporting context)

Create a new column where the values are stored and separated by commas.

```
 c = df.str.replace('Access Point:', '')
 s =np.where(df == 'Yes', ['{}, '.format(x) for x in c], '')
 df['new'] = pd.Series[''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s], index=df.index 
 df.drop[['all columns where data was pulled from']] 

output: 


       New:
   User 1: main site, twitter, blog, search
   User 2  blog, facebook, blog, email
```

I need to separate the two questions so I would have

Output

```
         New Access,                 Used This:
User 1   twitter, mainsite           blog, Search  
User 2   blog facebook               blog, email
```

now, the output i'm getting is brilliant, however, the data frame I have has around 190 columns, and I need to run the above code on a select amount of columns at a time, which I cannot figure out how to do! If I don't do this, the script runs throughout the whole CSV, creating one column pulling all the "Yes"'s into a single column. Whilst this is essentially what I wanted to do, it makes the data impossible to report off, as I need to replace and remove specific columns at a time before importing into a BI tool.

I've attempted to try the below:

```
    c['column names'] = df.str.replace('Access Point:', '')
and c = df.['column names'].str.replace('Access Point:', '')
```

but to no avail.

I hope this is clear!

Cheers,
Datanovice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I came to a solution which worked for me,

I split the columns into new data frames, edited each set of columns as needed and then used the following line at the end:

```
finaldf = pd.concat([df, df1, df2, df3, df4, df5], axis=1)
```

There is probably a slicker way to get this done, and i'll most likely laugh at this post a few months down the line, but I guess this was a fix for now.

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution!